# How to open and read number of files in the same directory and how to define global variable to read files

Tags: python, file, directory, global

I want to open and read number of files in the same directory one by one. and perform two functions on them. I'm facing two problems:

**1** I don't know how to define a global variable for the threshold_file which used in another function as well.
**2** This code returns the name of the files correctly but an error occurred

```
for file in os.listdir("C:/Users/Mariam/PycharmProjects/Group/Copy"):
        if file.endswith('b.txt'):
            threshold_file = open(file,'r')
            readThreshold_file()
            position_comparisonFn()

threshold_file = open(file,'r')

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '1000b.txt'
```

Answer (score 2):

The **file** variable in your code only stores the file name.
But while opening a file you should provide the relative path as well.

In your case just append *C:/Users/Mariam/PycharmProjects/Group/Copy* to the **file** variable and your code will work fine.

Comment: Did it helped you?
You can tick it then :)

Answer (score 0):

First - Declare the file variable as a global outside of the function as follows (without quotes)
"global threshold_file". Then specify to the function that you are using a global variable.

Second - Should be same as 'Shrey's comment'. Detailed below

```
def func1():
    global threshold_file
    for file in os.listdir("C:/Users/Mariam/PycharmProjects/Group/Copy"):
        if file.endswith('b.txt'):
            threshold_file = open("C:/Users/Mariam/PycharmProjects/Group/Copy/"+file,'r')
            readThreshold_file()
            position_comparisonFn()

def func2():
    global threshold_file
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: My pleasure! I'm glad that it helped. If you're familiar with the process of [marking an answer as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answer) , please do so. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

For your two questions:

#### 1. To define a global variable for the threshold_file

Outside of the functions, usually at the top of the code after your 'imports' section, setup your 'global' variables that you want to share like so:

```
# Globals
threshold_file = ""
```

Then, in each function that you want to use that variable, you have to tell Python that you want to use that 'global' variable with the `global` prefix, like so:

```
def foo():
    global threshold_file  # Here
    for file in os.listdir("C:/Users/Mariam/PycharmProjects/Group/Copy"):
        if file.endswith('b.txt'):
            threshold_file = open(file,'r')
            readThreshold_file()
            position_comparisonFn()
```

Note: You can use the variable without the `global` prefix, but you'll just have read-only access. In the `foo` function above, you need it, since you intend to update/write-to the value

#### 2. Error

Store the "C:/Users/Mariam/PycharmProjects/Group/Copy" as a var, perhaps as a global, now that you know how

```
p = r"C:/Users/Mariam/PycharmProjects/Group/Copy"  # prefix with 'r' for literal string
```

and use the var in your `open()` function

```
...
threshold_file = open(p + r'/' + file,'r')  # 'file' is just the filename... need the full path
...
```